# How to select pane in tmux via mouse over

Tags: mouse, tmux, mouse-click

As the title suggests, I want to select a pane in tmux by just doing mouse over on the pane, like it can be done with Gnome Terminal. I don't want to click the pane to select it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe this is (easily) possible. The only reason that clicking between panes is possible is because your terminal application will forward mouse position to the terminal application ***on mouse click***.

As an example, enable this in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
```

With this enabled, the terminal cursor can be dragged around inside a `tmux` pane. This shows why it is possible to click between panes, and resize panes with your mouse. Your terminal application (`xterm`, for example) does the [broadcasting of mouse cursor location to the terminal application, ***when you click***](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking). `tmux` can then use that information to, for example, move the terminal cursor, or switch to/resize panes as I explained above.

I don't see any evidence online that someone has managed to do change `tmux` panes by hovering over a different one.

Unless you rewrite parts of a terminal application so that it always broadcasts mouse location (even when you don't click), and then alter `tmux` so that it always keeps track of it (or something similar), I don't see a solution.

I honestly just suggest adding this line to your `~/.tmux.conf` file. It allows you to change panes just by clicking on a different one, which I don't see being much more inconvenient than only hovering over it:

```
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iTerm2 with Tmux you can check the iTerm > Preferences > Pointer > Focus follows mouse check box. This will probably only work with selected Tmux themes but could be worth giving it a try.